# Problems with istitle using def

Tags: python, string

I am new to programming.

My task is to write a function called `all_title_case` that takes as argument a list of strings called `word_list`. The function has to return `True` if each word in `word_list` is in title case; otherwise it has to return `False`.

This is what I have done so far:

```
word_list = [
    "This Is A String In Title Case",
    "This is Not a String in Title case",
    "THIS IS NOT A STRING IN TITLE CASE"
    ]

def all_title_case():
    if word_list.istitle():
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
all_title_case()
```

I get the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'istitle'
```

Comment: Note that as per the assignment your function must take argument `word_list` and you need to supply one when calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want

```
def all_title_case():
    return all(w.istitle() for w in word_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

your calling `istitle()` on the whole list, what you should do is iterate through
the list and call it on each item, also it's better to pass args to a function instead of using global variables.

```py
word_list = [
    "This Is A String In Title Case",
    "This is Not a String in Title case",
    "THIS IS NOT A STRING IN TITLE CASE"
    ]

def all_title_case(word_lst):
    for word in word_lst:
        if not word.istitle():
            return False
    return True

all_title_case(word_lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

`istitle ()` is applicable to single strings, and does exactly what you need.

However you are applying it to *a list* of strings. What you have to do is to loop on each element of the list:

```
def all_title_case():
    for el in word_list:
        if not el.istitle():
            return False

    return True
```

Please note how a single element not satisfying the condition is enough to return `False`.